# What kind of GWT widget I can use to return a file

Tags: java, gwt

I am using GWT to build a web application. On the client side, I use Anchor, but I don't use the Href property to get the resource, because of the requirements of the application. Now I can call the server side code and return a file. Since GWT doesn't support java.io.File on the client side, what widget I can use so that I can download the file?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

`Window.open` or `Window.Location.assign` maybe?

but it probably just moves the problem: what are you "requirements of the application" that prevent you from setting the anchor's href?